# AngularJS $inject - Difference Between Dot And Bracket Accessor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

For an AngularJS component

```
function controller () {}
```

What is the difference between

```
//dot-notation
controller.$inject = ["service"]
```

and

```
//bracket-notation
controller["$inject"] = ["service"]
```

with respect to how AngularJS processes it? The bracket-notation doesn't seem to be working in one particular project.

There is a lot of JS code and I am more interested in knowing what could someone have written to cause this basic JS behaviour to change? If I know a code pattern to look for then I could debug better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. From JS point of view this notations are equal and both works.

```
function myctrl(var1) {
  var1.name = 'World';
}

myctrl['$inject'] = ['$scope'];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gDJHI76A8Mz2Y5Erm2s0?p=preview

Problem may be with some build tool you use.

Comment: Thanks. It is quite interesting that this very code is failing for me in my project. I cut out all the build tools and attempted adding a plain hand cranked JS file. I say this because I am using typescript and that's where this issue surfaced. I'll debug further to figure where it is going wrong.